# Webforms 403.14 Error IIS 7 when viewing Friendly Urls

Tags: iis-7, webforms, friendly-url

I am running into trouble using the Friendly Urls nuget package in my Webforms website. Works locally and on my vanilla Amazon web server. However, it causes errors on our server at work. I have tried adding the bundle stuff in the web.config etc. but nothing seems to work. Anyone seen this before? And preferably, did you manage to solve it? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and it bugged me for ages. I noticed my server I was trying to get my site working on had a stack more modules listed in IIS than the server that worked. I removed them from the Website on IIS and redeployed the code and it worked perfectly. I did try doing an IIS reset and an app pool recycle but they didn't work which surprised me but definitely a redeployment did the trick.

It's worth saying that its likely that not all the modules need removing but when I was testing I didnt redeploy after I removed a module and I still had the problem.

Hope this helps